# Is there function to perform calculation on decimal column value of mongodb in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to calculate the total discount **percentage(%)** of the Item based on Item price and Item sales price.

But column data store in **mongodb** collection in **decimal** formate like **11,000**

so when performing calculation as

```
$itemPrice = 10,000;
$itemSalesPrice = 11,000;

$discount = (($itemPrice - $itemSalesPriceprice) / $itemPrice) * 100;
```

PHP returns Error as

> **A non well formed numeric value encountered**
> Blockquote

I have tried to use implicit conversion to **float** but value retains is till comma.
Like

```
var_dump((float)$itemPrice);
```

The output is

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to change the data stored in database, you could just do a str_replace like this.

```
$itemPriceFromDB = '10,000'; // get value from database as string
$itemSalesPriceFromDB = '11,000'; // get value from database as string

$itemPrice = (float) str_replace(',', '.', $itemPriceFromDB );
$itemSalesPrice= (float) str_replace(',', '.', $itemSalesPriceFromDB );

$discount = (($itemPrice - $itemSalesPrice) / $itemPrice) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function toFloat($numeric):float
{
 return (float)str_replace(',','',$numeric);
}


$itemPrice =toInt("10,000");
$itemSalesPrice = toInt("11,000");

$discount = (($itemPrice - $itemSalesPriceprice) / $itemPrice) * 100;
```